# FormClosing delegate not working with ShowDialog() method

Tags: c#, winforms, delegates, showdialog, formclosing

In my C# WinForms program I have some forms and I show one of them as a dialog:

```
MyForm mf = new MyForm();
mf.ShowDialog();
```

But when I try to assigne a form closing event for them, it is not working;

```
mf.FormClosing += delegate { MessageBox.Show("Dialog is closed.")};
```

What is the problem?

P.S: It works fine when I call the form using mf.Show() method.

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

"Not working" is hopelessly ambiguous.  There's a semi-colon missing in your snippet.  Having to guess, don't assign the FormClosing event *after* calling ShowDialog(), that's too late.  This works fine:

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
        using (var mf = new Form2()) {
            mf.FormClosing += delegate { MessageBox.Show("Dialog is closed."); };
            mf.ShowDialog();
        }
    }
```

Comment: yeah what I ment was it does not trigger the event, with your code it is working now thanks.

Answer (score 4):

What is the sequence you use? First you have to register the event, then call mf.ShowDialog().

```
MyForm mf = new MyForm();
mf.FormClosing += delegate { MessageBox.Show("Dialog is closed.")};
mf.ShowDialog();
```

You write in the MessageBox "*Dialog is closed*", but you register to `FormClosing`. Please note, that there is a [FormClosed](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.formclosed.aspx) and a [FormClosing](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.formclosing.aspx)-event. This are different events.

Answer (score 2):

As a test, try changing `ShowDialog` to `Show`. The behavior (how events are fired) is indeed different. You may need to call the dispose method explicitly.

http://www.dotnetmonster.com/Uwe/Forum.aspx/dotnet-vb/56720/If-I-want-FormClosing-and-FormClose-to-run-am-I-suppose-to-call